# Using Pandas with Python, delete row in data frame if word has appeared three times already

Tags: python, list, frame

Example data frame:

```
Name Age
Bob 20
Frank 50
Bob 21
Bob 22
Bob 5
Frank 10
Bob 60
```

I want to remove any row if a word in the `"Name"` column has appeared three times already (in this case, row 5 and 7 are to be deleted.)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print(df[df.groupby("Name").cumcount() < 3])
```

Prints:

```
    Name  Age
0    Bob   20
1  Frank   50
2    Bob   21
3    Bob   22
5  Frank   10
```